# How to prove $|q|\ge 1 \Rightarrow |a|\ge |d|$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-writing

Let $a,d,q \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $a=dq$

How do I show that $|q| \ge 1 \Rightarrow |a| \ge |d|$?

I've tried:

$|q|\ge 1 \Rightarrow (q>1 \text{, if } q>0) \text { or } (-q>1 \text{, if } q<0)$

So, I need to consider the above cases separately:

$\begin{align}
q>1 \text{, if } q>0 & \Rightarrow & (dq \ge d, \text{ if } d>0) \text{ Or } (dq \ge d, \text{ if } d<0) \\
& \Rightarrow & (a \ge d, \text{ if } d>0) \text{ Or } (a \ge d, \text{ if } d<0) 
\end{align}$

$\begin{align}
-q>1 \text{, if } q<0 & \Rightarrow & (-dq \ge d, \text{ if } d>0) \text{ Or } (-dq \ge d, \text{ if } d<0) \\
& \Rightarrow & (-a \ge d, \text{ if } d>0) \text{ Or } (-a \ge d, \text{ if } d<0) 
\end{align}$

Now I have:

$\begin{align} |q| \ge 1 &\Rightarrow & (a \ge d, \text{ if } d>0) \text{ Or } (a \ge d, \text{ if } d<0) \\
& \text{ Or} &\\
& & (-a \ge d, \text{ if } d>0) \text{ Or } (-a \ge d, \text{ if } d<0) \\
& \Rightarrow & (a \ge d \text { Or } -a \ge d, \text { if } d>0) \text { Or } (a\ge d \text{ Or }-a \ge d, \text{ if } d<0)
 \end{align}$

What do I do next? Having absolute values on both sides of an inequality is confusing me alot.

Answer (score 3):

We have

$$a=dq\implies |a|=|dq|=|d|\times|q|\ge|d|\times1=|d|$$

Comment: Thanks. I never thought of that approach before. But what about my method. I know its long winded but is it possible to reach the same conclusion too?